# Excel - Is there a function to return a number based on which string is in a cell, like CHOOSE but not?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a function `=Func(A1, "Alex, "Betty", "Charlie")` that returns the index of the matched entry. If this function is put into B1:B13, it would show

```
"Charlie"   3
"Alex"      1
"Alex"      1
"Alex"      1
"Charlie"   3
"Charlie"   3
"Betty"     2
"Charlie"   3
"Charlie"   3
"Betty"     2
"Betty"     2
"Betty"     2
"Alex"      1
```

I thought CHOOSE would do this at first glance, but it returns a reference based on an integer, the inverse of what I need.

Is there an existing function that does this that I missed, would I have to make a more complicated function out of something like nested ifs or vlookup, or would I have to write a function in VBA?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Do the strings need to be parameters to the function, or could they be elsewhere in the spreadsheet, or in another sheet in the workbook?

Comment: @RandyOrrison As in =Func(A1, C1, C2, C3) where the strings are now in C1:C3 instead of embedded in the function? I think that could work, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can put the values to compare to into a range elsewhere in the spreadsheet, you can use the LOOKUP function.  LOOKUP looks for its first argument in the range specified in the second argument, and returns the corresponding value from the range in the third argument.  You'll have to add a range specifying the value you want.

For example, I create the lookup table in F1:F3 and G1:G3:

```
    F         G
1   Alex      1
2   Betty     2
3   Charlie   3
```

Then the function to use is

```
    B
1   =LOOKUP(A1,$F$1:$F$3,$G$1:$G$3)
2   =LOOKUP(A2,$F$1:$F$3,$G$1:$G$3)
```

In cell B1, LOOKUP looks for A1 ("Charlie"), finds it in F3, and returns the value from G3, which is 3. In cell B2, LOOKUP looks for A2 ("Alex"), finds it in F1, and returns the value from G1, which is 1.

You could also put the lookup table in another sheet in the workbook, if you don't want it in the main sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what your source data looks like, but the MATCH function will look at a single value and return its position within an array.

If A1:A4 is

```
Alex
Betty
Charlie
Betty
```

and in B1 you put

```
=MATCH(A1,$A$1:$A$4)
```

B1 will return

```
1
```

Then simply fill B1 down through B4 and you'll have your result.

Comment: Thinking about it, I see your data is indeed in A1:A4.  So put `=MATCH(A1,$A$1:$A$4)` in B1 then fill it down to B2:B4 and you'll have your result.  I edited my answer to include this.

Comment: Match depends on position, not value. It would only work like that if I kept the first few entries in order. If I were to sort the table the numbers would change. I updated the question to reduce confusion about being in order.